# Managing security on UDP socket

Tags: network-programming

I am looking at developing my first multiplayer RTS game and I'm naturally going to be using UDP sockets for receiving/sending data.

One thing that I've been trying to figure out is how to protect these ports from being flooded by fake packets in a DoS attack. Normally a firewall would protect against flood attacks but I will need to allow packets on the ports that I'm using and will have to rely on my own software to reject bogus packets. What will stop people from sniffing my  packets, observing any authentication or special structure I'm using and spamming me with similar packets? Source addresses can easily be changed to make detecting and banning offenders nearly impossible. Are there any widely accepted methods for protecting against these kind of attacks?

I know all about the differences between UDP and TCP and so please don't turn this into a lecture about that.

===================== EDIT =========================

I should add that I'm also trying to work out how to protect against someone 'hacking' the game and cheating by sending packets that I believe are coming from my game. Sequencing/sync numbers or id's could easily be faked. I could use an encryption but I am worried about how much this would slow the responses of my server and this wouldn't provide protection from DoS.

I know these are basic problems every programmer using a UDP socket must encounter, but for the life of me I cannot find any relevant documentation on methods for working around them!

Any direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The techniques you need would not be specific to UDP: you are looking for general message authentication to handle spoofing, rate throttling to handle DoS, and server-side state heuristics ("does this packet make sense?") to handle client hacks.

For handling DoS efficiently, you need layers of detection.  First drop invalid source addresses without even looking at the contents.  Put a session ID at the start of each packet with an ID that isn't assigned or doesn't match the right source.  Next, keep track of the arrival rates per session.  Start dropping from addresses that are coming in too fast.  These techniques will block everything except someone who is able to sniff legitimate packets in real-time.

But a DoS attack based on real-time sniffing would be very rare and the rate of attack would be limited to the speed of a single source network.  The only way to block packet sniffing is to use encryption and checksums, which is going to be a lot of work.  Since this is your "first multiplayer RTS", I suggest doing everything short of encryption.

If you do decide to use encryption, AES-128 is relatively fast and very secure.  Brian Gladman's reference Rijndael implementation is a good starting point if you really want to optimize, or there are plenty of AES libraries out there.  Checksumming the clear-text data can be done with a simple CRC-16.  But that's probably overkill for your likely attack vectors.

Comment: Great summary, thank you very much! I'm not sure how to tell if a source IP is invalid? If the game is played on a laptop/smartphone, then an IP could change for the session. Here is what I will do so far:
*Login authentication to begin active session
*Add session ID to all packets
*Tag each packet with the action it is (move/shoot/keepalive) and limit the number per second of each
*Have the server verify with the client how many packets of type X were sent in the last 30 seconds
*Logically remove any packets that appear corrupt or faked
*Terminate sessions that violate these rules too often

Answer (score 5):

Most important of all: Never trust the client! Always keep track of everything server-side. If a packet arrives that seems bogus (like a unit moving Y units per second while it should only be able to mov X units per second) then simply drop the packet.

Also, if the number of packets per second grows to big, start dropping packets as well.

And don't use the UDP packets for "unimportant" things... In-game chat and similar things can go though normal TCP streams.

Comment: Of course I will process all messages from my client to make sure they are legit, but the process of un-encrypting(if I take that path) and processing those packets to the point I know they are bogus will put enough strain on a server for a good DoS attack!

Comment: @Scotty That's why the big online games all use a multi-server architecture: One server to handle connections, one database server, one "application" server. (Replace "one server" with "a server cluster").

Comment: On a side not - I recall learning that you cannot use TCP and UDP at the same time as they both work on the same network later (or something)... Of course that may just be on a per-port basis, or I could just be completely wrong :)

Comment: So you're basically saying, make sure the server is beefy enough to survive any DoS attacks? It seems to me like there must be better methods to detect dodgy activity earlier.

Comment: @Scotty TCP and UDP are completely different, and can even be used with the same port numbers. The network stack takes care to separate those.

Comment: @Scotty About the servers, yes. The servers for something like WoW are extremely beefy. :) Also, that's another reason the big ones split up the games into shards.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the TCP/UDP part up. However I'm still looking for more ideas on limiting DoS potential.